# How do I output required entries from a CSV file into a new file and count the number of entries?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a CSV file of a table that has some entries that are blank. I want my code to look through all the entries for each row (except the first) and count the number of blank entries > store the blank entries per row and separate them with a comma into a file called temp_file > then I want the code to count the number of blank entries in that file and give me a value e.g. if it is,,, then the output should be 3.

This is currently what I have:

```
sed 1d ${FILENAME} | while read ln

do

echo $ln | tail -1 PMRExceptions.csv | tr "," "\n" | grep -nx '^$' | cut -d":" -f1

PMRNUM=echo $ln | awk -F"," '{print $2}'

PMRMGR=echo $ln | awk -F"," '{print $3}'

COUNT=less $TEMPFILE | wc -l
```

**this part over here is supposed to count the number of blank entries**

```
while read line
do
columns=`head -1 $FILENAME | awk -F"," -v ln=$line '{print $ln}'`
```

The value that I get is 0, no matter what I change. I think that the entries are not being stored in the tempfile.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` to count the number of comma-delimited fields on each line of input that are empty (excluding the header line):

```
awk -F ',' 'NR > 1 { c=0; for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) if ($i == "") ++c; print c }' file.csv
```

This assumes that no field contains embedded commas.

Example:

```
$ cat file.csv
A,B,C
1,,0
all,bar,none
my,field,here
no,data,
```

```
$ awk -F ',' 'NR > 1 { c=0; for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) if ($i == "") ++c; print c }' file.csv
1
0
0
1
```

Related:

- [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716)

Comment: which part of the code will i need to replace this with?

Comment: @infiniteoscillation All of it. The `awk` command I have in the answer reads the original CSV file and counts the number of empty fields on each line.